# Flex LineChart data points don't match tick marks / axis labels

Tags: apache-flex

Can anyone tell me why the data points on the LineChart don't line up with the corresponding tick mark / horizontal axis label?

See adobe's example (at the bottom of the page):

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/charts/DateTimeAxis.html

See how the data for 7/28/05 is to the right of the 7/28/05 tick mark / label?

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this - http://www.munkiihouse.com/?p=69

Seems that setting the DateTimeAxis' displayLocalTime to true does the trick. :)